# Change separator property of a adaptive card bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I'm using Separator attribute in my textblock of adaptive card, property is working but i need to update the Thickness and line color of Separator below is the code, but its not getting reflected. I'm using bot framework v3

```
SeparatorConfig separatorConfig = new SeparatorConfig();

separatorConfig.LineThickness = 2;
separatorConfig.LineColor = "Black";

card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = QuestionValue,
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
    Wrap = true,
    Separator = true,                                        
});
```

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes, i have implemented it and issue is resolved.

Comment: That's good to hear. Would you go ahead and upvote my answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just on a side note, the answer from Kyle is correct, you can't change the separators if you're not the one rendering the card.

Just on your code sample there, you should really learn about Adaptive Card templating. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/

it makes the whole story so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the purpose of Adaptive Cards. When you author an Adaptive Card, you intentionally give up a lot of control about how that card is going to look. This is because Adaptive Cards are meant to adapt to their environments, so that they look like they belong in whatever application is rendering them. The control you're trying to have over the separator is actually one of those things that's not up to the card author, but instead up to the card *renderer*.

Second, you need to consider some red flags in your code. The `AdaptiveCards` library you're using actually contains code that can be used by card authors as well as code that can be used by card renderers. The [`SeparatorConfig`](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/dotnet/Library/AdaptiveCards/Rendering/SeparatorConfig.cs) class is in the `AdaptiveCards.Rendering` namespace, which implies that it's meant to be used by renderers. Also notice that while you're creating the `SeparatorConfig` object and assigning values to its properties, you're not actually passing it into the `AdaptiveTextBlock` or doing anything with it at all.

You can only configure the separator if you have control over the client application. If you're using someone else's client application like Microsoft Teams then you have to accept that the separator's appearance is not yours to configure. If you're making your own client application then you can customize the separator using [HostConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config).

See [my latest blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) for more information about Adaptive Cards.

Comment: my question is how can we pass the properties which i have set to my textblock